# SonarQube 8.6 - Disable Quality Profiles for certain languages

Tags: sonarqube

Small question on SonarQube 8.6 (but maybe can apply to other versions)

I just downloaded SonarQube, and out of the box, it has quality profiles for many languages (C, C#, Ruby, etc...)

I am only interested in analyzing few languages (JAVA in my case).

Hence, I would like to simply disable the other languages. I am sure I will not be needing them.

How to achieve this please? I only see "Create" and "Restore" from the admin view.

Just interested in disabling the languages I do not need, even if I do not use them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flags/properties `sonar.language` and `sonar.profile` both deprecated since 4.5, have been [dropped since 7.7](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.7/setup/upgrade-notes/).

SonarQube will now analyze all code for which you have [installed language plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/analysis/languages/overview/).

To NOT analyze a particular language, uninstall the language plugin (Administration | Marketplace | Installed - `{SQ_URL}/admin/marketplace?filter=installed`).

Alternatively, consider what is a **default** Quality Profile:

> Default - Every project not specifically associated with a quality
> profile will be associated to this one by default

> For each language there is a default profile. All projects not
> explicitly assigned to some other profile will be analyzed with the
> default. Ideally, all projects will use the same profile for a
> language

You could create a dummy quality profile for each language of no interest consisting of no rules, make that the **default**. That would allow you to keep the plugins and retain the option assign language specific profiles as needed in future.

Another option you might try is under `{SQ_URL}/admin/settings`, you can edit the language specific settings to delete the default extensions that are scanned (ie: XML:.xml|.xsd|.xsl, JavaScript:js|.jsx|.vue). I imagine if there's no match, it would ignore scanning those languages.

There is also a general exclusions category `{SQ_URL}/admin/settings?category=exclusions`, but that may be more work to maintain.

**WARNING**: There is always a risk if you include code in your application but choose not to scan it, especially for **Security Hotspots** and **Vulnerabilities**. For example, we surprised to discover occurrences of [Links with "target=_blank" are security-sensitive](https://rules.sonarsource.com/html/tag/phishing/RSPEC-5148) [**Vulnerability: Blocker - Phishing**] since we had previously not scanned HTML as we were a "Java shop".